# How can I install  an unsigned application on an iPhone from Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

How can I install  an unsigned application on an iPhone from Xcode? I am using last version of Xcode and the iOS 5 SDK.

Comment: You can't do it with the official SDK. Apple simply forbids it.

Comment: It has to be signed. That's the whole point and incentive of joining the developer program with a paid account - to be able to test & deploy to an iDevice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Apple wants people to sign up with their developer program, and so the only way to install an unsigned app might involve jail breaking, but I don't know enough as I've never jailbroken an iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

**CAUTION!** This DOES require a jailbroken iOS Device.

**Yes, you CAN!**

If you've built it on your own, you can simply use your phone as developer device (if you don't know how, just google it, I don't remember yet).

The trick is to force Xcode to don't try to code sign your app. If you don't, you'll get an error every time, you try to build it.

Go to Terminal and type:

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist
```

(You might replace iPhoneOS5.0 with your target SDK)

You'll be asked for your admin password.

Now change the value for the key `CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED` to `NO`.

You are almost done.

Go to your project settings, look for "Code Signing" and set all values to `Don't Code Sign`.

Set the active scheme to your iPhone instead of iPhone 5.0 Simulator and go to `Product → Build For → Build For Archiving`

Now go to your Organizer Window, head for your iPhone, go to Applications, press the plus sign at left bottom and choose your build path.
In Xcode4 it's `/Users/you/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourApp/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/` by default.

Select your App binary (it will have a "forbidden" badge, because you're on Mac architecture) and click open.

Wait a few seconds and now your app should be available from your SpringBoard.

Comment: You said "might". I confirmed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're not ready to purchase the license yet. That's when you require [JailCoder](http://www.jailcoder.com/) - an easy to use app for tweaking your project and Xcode. Purchase the license and publish your app when you're happy testing with JailCoder.

Note: Here also a jailbroken device is required.

Answer (score 0):

It would require jailbreaking, which I don't see why not because my jailbroken iPad doesn't have a virus after probably 300 apps. All the apps from the default repositories are checked and don't have a virus.