# how to build unsigned application for iphone 5.1 using xcode + phonegap and create .ipa file without apple developer program?

Tags: xcode4.3

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664577/distribute-unsigned-app-iphone-for-jailbroken-iphone-with-no-cydia)Distribute unsigned Application for iphone?

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204969/how-can-i-install-an-unsigned-application-on-an-iphone-from-xcode)install unsigned Application on iphone.i have changed sdksetting and project setting .but that is not helpful for me?so give me a proper solution?

Answer (score 1):

you should try [JailCoder](http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/), it patches everything for you

Comment: JailCoder website is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

1) Ad hoc distribution is your only option (and is limited to 100 (as of this typing) users:

More info: [Xcode App Distribution to Friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701273/xcode-app-distribution-to-friends)

2) Install somebody else's unsigned application (requires a jailbreak) or run your own code / project on your own iPhone (only requires provisioning)?

More info: [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Extensive (code-signing) docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/CodeSigning/CodeSigning.html

Comment: Ad hoc distribution still requires that you be a member of the iOS developer program.